# Nested Eithers with different error types

Tags: haskell, typeclass, either

I have a nested either with different error types, that looks like:

```
Either e1 (Either e2 a)
```

And I'd like a function that does something like:

```
Either e1 (Either e2 a) -> Either e2 a
```

More generally, is there a typeclass that matches this pattern?

Comment: What you’re asking for doesn’t make sense unless the function is partial or you provide it with some extra information. What if the value on the outside is `Left`? Then you don’t have a value of type `e2` *or* `a`, only of type `e1`, so you can’t construct an `Either e2 a`.

Comment: I would understand that you want to group the errors (for instance on the left), so that the resulting type is `Either (Either e1 e2) a`. But now you somehow wish to omit a certain type of errors.

Comment: So you want a function that takes an error and makes the error not happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Your function is impossible!

What you’re asking for doesn’t really make sense as it stands. Let’s look at the type of your function:

```
f :: Either e1 (Either e2 a) -> Either e2 a
```

Assuming this function is total (as the vast majority of functions in Haskell really ought to be), we need to produce a value of type `Either e2 a` for *any* input of type `Either e1 (Either e2 a)`. To try and implement this, let’s consider all of the “shapes” the input can come in.

It turns out that values of the type `Either e1 (Either e2 a)` can come in three possible shapes:

```
Left _
Right (Left _)
Right (Right _)
```

The bottom two shapes are easy to handle. In fact, we can just map any `Right` value to itself:

```
f (Right x) = x
```

However, this doesn’t handle the outer `Left` case. We can start by writing the pattern:

```
f (Left x) = ???
```

In the above pattern, we get a single value, `x`, with type `e1`. We need to produce a value of type `Either e2 a`. This means we essentially need a function with the following type:

```
g :: e1 -> Either e2 a
```

But wait! That type is clearly impossible to satisfy, since we need either an `e2` or an `a`, but all we have is an `e1`. Therefore, we *can’t* implement that case (assuming we don’t infinitely loop or use `error` or `undefined`). We’re stuck.

## Solution 1: provide more information

Without knowing what you’re actually trying to do, it’s hard to offer a good solution to this problem. I can at least offer a few possibilities, and maybe one of them will be relevant to your use case.

One easy solution is to provide a way to map `e1` values to `e2`. That way, we can normalize all errors to `e2`. Implementing this is very easy with the help of the `either` function:

```
f :: (e1 -> e2) -> Either e1 (Either e2 a) -> Either e2 a
f g = either (Left . g) id
```

You could also do this by applying the mapping function to the left hand side of the outer `Either`, then using the monadic `join` function to merge the two layers:

```
import Data.Bifunctor

f :: (e1 -> e2) -> Either e1 (Either e2 a) -> Either e2 a
f g = join . first g
```

## Solution 2: change the result type

Another way we could handle this would be to tweak the result to encode both possibilities. We could produce a value of type `Either (Either e1 e2) a` to hold either possible error. This is also fairly easy to write with the `either` function:

```
f :: Either e1 (Either e2 a) -> Either (Either e1 e2) a
f = either (Left . Left) (either (Left . Right) Right)
```

However, that’s probably clearer written with pattern-matching instead of `either`:

```
f :: Either e1 (Either e2 a) -> Either (Either e1 e2) a
f (Left x) = Left (Left x)
f (Right (Left x)) = Left (Right x)
f (Right (Right x)) = Right x
```

Comment: Thanks, your post was very well written and helped to answer and clarify the question in my own mind as well.

To clarify, e1 and e2 have similar structure as errors, so I would be looking at mapping e1 errors to e2 errors, so solution 1 works very well for my case.